# Facebook Javascript API keeps reconnecting

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm building a site which, when the user connects to Facebook, appends a profile picture to a div, amongst other things. When I leave the site open for a while and come back, I see that the same profile picture has been appended multiple times, so clearly the Facebook connection closes and reopens every so often.

Is there any way to stop this?

Thanks

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '219892158204692',
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below
  // will be handled.
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs.
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        fbconnect = true;
        $('#fbloginbutton').hide();
        $('#friendcontainer').append('<span id="loader"><center>Loading...</center></span>');
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they
      // have logged in to the app.
        FB.api(
            "/me",
            function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                fbid = response['id'];
                user['id'] = response['id'];
                getuserhighscore(user['id']);
                userpercentile(parseInt(user['highscore']));
                $('#statscontainer').append('<span class="label">Highest Score</span>: '+user['highscore']+'<br>');
                $('#statscontainer').append('<span class="label">Percentile (global)</span>: '+user['percentile']+'<br>');
                drawuserchart(user['id']);

                }
            }
        );



        FB.api(
            "/fql?q=select%20uid%2C%20first_name%2C%20is_app_user%20from%20user%20where%20uid%20in%20(select%20uid2%20from%20friend%20where%20uid1%3Dme())%20and%20is_app_user%3D1",
            function (response) {
                console.log('friends installed:');
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response['data'][0].id);
                var responseArray = []; 
                responseArray.push(response);
                console.log(responseArray); 
                user['friends'] = response['data'].length;
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    for (var i=0;i<response['data'].length;i++){
                        friend = response['data'][i];
                        console.log('friend coming up');
                        console.log(friend);
                        friends.push(friend.uid);
                        $('#friendcontainer').append('<div class="friendbox" id="'+friend.uid+'"></div>');
                           $('#'+friend.uid+'').append('<img class="friendpic" src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+friend.uid+'/picture?height=60&width=60&type=square">');
                           $('#'+friend.uid+'').append('<div class="friendname">'+friend.first_name+'</div>');
                        gethighscore(friend.uid);
                        $('#'+friend.uid+'').append(' - '+friendscores[i]+'');
                        console.log(friendscores);
                    }
                    $('#loader').remove();

                    user['friendrank'] = 1;



                    for (var i=0;i<friendscores.length;i++){
                        if(friendscores[i] > user['highscore']){
                            user['friendrank']++;
                        }
                    }

                    $('#statscontainer').append('<span class="label">Rank (among friends)</span>: '+user['friendrank']+'<br>');

                } else { 
                    console.log(response.error) 
                }
            }
        );
        console.log(friends);
        console.log(user)
        FB.api(
            "/me/picture",
            {
                "redirect": false,
                "height": "100",
                "type": "normal",
                "width": "100"
            },
            function (response) {
              if (response && !response.error) {
                user['picture'] = response['data']['url'];
                console.log(user['picture']);
                $('#thumbnail').append('<img id="thumbnailpic" src="'+user['picture']+'">');
              }
            }
        );
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so.
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
      FB.login();
    } else {
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login()
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook.
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful.
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
      $('#sidebar').slideDown("slow");
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `so clearly the Facebook connection closes and reopens every so often`- that's totally incorrect. Ofcourse you are doing something wrong here, you have to show some code

Comment: Ah okay, sorry! I've added the code to the OP

Comment: What's in your console log might also be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FB.Event.subscribe` on `auth.authResponseChange` is triggered whenever there's change in the auth. A user session is maintained for some minutes, so what's happening is the event is triggered after sometime and the photos are appended again.

You should not write this whole code in this event block.

So, if you want to do this all in this same page, what you can do is, maintain a bool, say `bool isLoaded=false;`, now when your call is completed: `isLoaded=true;` indicating that the data is loaded.

And make your API calls whenever it is false, just like this-

```
if (response.status === 'connected') {
   if(isLoaded){
      fbconnect = true;
      ....
      ....
   }
   else
      // dont do anything
}
```

Hope that helps!